# How to route html pages on clicks in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am a newbie in Meteor. I am developing an app having a login page that must redirect to certain pages as per the login id.There are certain click events which opens up html pages.I have the hard code data in the pages to check the flow now.I have the html pages as well designed, but I am not able to link them for click events and login. Please help.

Comment: you need to use a router it has those options

Comment: I am trying the iron:router way, but seems I am still missing out something.     `<template name="Login">
   <form name="LoginForm" class="form-signin">
          Username: <input type="text" name="userId" value="" id="username" class="form-control shadow" placeholder="Enter username" autofocus>
 Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="form-control shadow" placeholder="Enter password">           
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-black btn-block loginsubmit" placeholder="">
   </form>
</template>`

Comment: `Template.Login.events({
 'submit form': function(){
  event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('[name=userId]').val();
  var password = $('[name=password]').val();
  if(username == '' && password ==''){
   alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
  }
  else if( username =='deal' && password ==''){
   alert("You are logged in as a Deal manager");
   Router.go("/dashboard.html");   
  }
  else if( username =='practice' && password ==''){
   alert("You are logged in as a Practice manager");
  }  
 }
  });`

Comment: you need to edit your answer with this code can't really read it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

In your HTML file, something like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Duckbilled Platypus</title>
</head>

<template name='layout'>
  {{> banner}}
  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="banner">
  <h1 class="chocolatefont">Platypi of the World Unite! (Duckbilled, that is)</h1>
  <hr/>
</template>

<template name="main">
  <div id="templateMain" name="templateMain">
    <h2>RAVES</h2>
    <p>No Raves yet</p>
    <h2>RANTS</h2>
    <p>No Rants yet</p>
    <h2>RANDOM</h2>
    <a href="nfnoscar">The Legend of NFN Oscar</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="nfnoscarsdonut">NFN Oscar's donut</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="alliterationstation">Alliteration Station ("Ben's Bizarre Bazaar")</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="btakpm">Boomeranging Telescopic and Kaleidoscopic Phrase Mazes</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="acrostics">Acrostics</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="homonyms">Homonym Homie</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

...and then add whichever templates you want for the pages you want to route to; in my case, it's one for each "href" referenced in the anchor tags (nfnoscar, nfnoscarsdout. etc.)

The "yield" (which means, "insert here whatever the router says corresponds to the URL") requires Iron:Router, which you say you already have.

In your JS file, something like this:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'main',
  template: 'main'
});
Router.route('/nfnoscar', {
  name: 'nfnoscar',
  template: 'nfnoscar'
});
Router.route('/nfnoscarsdonut', {
  name: 'nfnoscarsdonut',
  template: 'nfnoscarsdonut'
});
Router.route('/alliterationstation', {
  name: 'alliterationstation',
  template: 'alliterationstation'
});
Router.route('/btakpm', {
  name: 'btakpm',
  template: 'btakpm'
});
Router.route('/homonyms', {
  name: 'homonyms',
  template: 'homonyms'
});
Router.route('/acrostics', {
  name: 'acrostics',
  template: 'acrostics'
});
```

Now, whichever link is clicked, the corresponding page is loaded by means of the "yield" and the Iron Router routing.

You can see this particular app and how it works when you click the links, etc., at my "sandbox" Meteorsite [here](http://platypus.meteor.com).